# Elements not drawing when paint() is directly invoked, but drawing when added to content pane

Tags: java, swing, jframe

A `Graph` object is being added to a `JFrame`. This object draws axes followed by a graph plot. When the object's `paint()` is invoked implicitly through the `JFrame` using:

```
this.getContentPane().add(new Graph());
```

both the axes and the function draw. However, when the `paint()` method is explicitly invoked, via:

```
Graph g = new Graph();
g.paint(this.getContentPane().getGraphics());
```

the axes do not draw, however the function does. The full constructor for the `JFrame` is as follows:

```
public GraphFrame() {
    super("");
    setSize(800, 800);
    setVisible(true);
    //One of the above blocks is called here
}
```

The function `paint` in object `Graph` is as follows:

```
public void paint(Graphics w) {
    w.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    w.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800); //Clears the screen
    w.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    w.drawLine(100, 0, 100, 800);
    w.drawLine(0, 700, 800, 700); //(Should) Draw the axes
    for(int i = 1; i < 650; i++) {
        //Draws the function
        //This is just a repeated drawLine call.
    }
}
```

Why would the axes draw when implicitly called when components paint, but not draw when explicitly invoked? Remember that the function draws (the block in the `for` loop), while the axes preceding the for loop do not.

Comment: Why are you calling `paint(...)` directly? This is most unusual to do and flies against most recommendations in the graphics tutorials and makes little sense in light of what you're trying to do. Have you gone through the Swing graphics tutorials? If not, you really should as there is much that they have to offer you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `paint` directly on a component. Also for custom painting in Swing use `paintComponent` rather than `paint` and remember to call `super.paintComponent(g)`. Also `getGraphics` returns a transient `Graphics` reference so should not be used for custom painting. In contrast the `Graphics` reference in `paint` (and `paintComponent`) is always  initialized correctly and will display graphical output as expected.

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)